# Can SonarQube be used for SAST for a dot net core version 3.2 application?

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, sonarqube, sast

For a dot net core 3.2 application, can we use SonarQube for Static Application Security Testing (SAST)? If not, then what could be the alternatives.
I am from the Java background and I am aware that plugins like FindSecBugs can be used with SonarQube for Java source code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube does SAST for a number of languages, including C# and Java.

Links to the security-related rules for C#: [Vulnerabilities](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/type/Vulnerability) and [Security Hotspots](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/type/Security%20Hotspot).

Other useful links:

- https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/security-rules/
- https://www.sonarqube.org/features/security/